# How to unit test a @Query() decorator with Jest in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to write unit tests for my NestJS application using Jest. I have a resolver with a @Query() decorator from [@nestjs/graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/graphql) that I want to test, but I'm not sure how to achieve 100% test coverage for the line that contains the @Query() decorator.

Here is the code for my resolver:

```js
    @Resolver(() => Person)
    export class MyResolver {
      @Query(() => Person, { name: 'personLogged' })
      async getPerson(
        @Token() tokenPersonLogged: string,
        @Context() context,
        @Profiles() personProfiles: string[],
      ): Promise<Person> {
        // ...
      }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's usually tested in the [end-to-end](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing) tests:

```js
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { Person } from '../src/person/person.model';
import { PersonModule } from '../src/person/person.module';
import { PersonService } from '../src/person/person.service';

describe('Person resolver', () => {
  // your mocks
  const person: Person = { name: 'John' };
  const personService: PersonService = { get: () => person };

  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    // if you don't have a standalone module, you might import the `AppModule` instead
    const fixture = await Test.createTestingModule({ imports: [PersonModule] })
      // register the mocks here
      .overrideProvider(PersonService).useValue(personService)
      .compile();
    app = fixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  test('personLogged', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/graphql')
      // pass the graphql query (or use a graphql client instead)
      .send({ query: '{ personLogged { name } }' })
      .expect(200)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body.data.personLogged).toEqual(person);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: In my case, I had to import the AppModule because I'm not working with standalone modules, but it resolved here. Thank you very much!!